# Ahow to use multiple terminals in the docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I know it is weird to use multiple terminals in the docker container.

My purpose is to test some commands and build a dockerfile with these commands finally.
So I need to use multiple terminals, say, two. One is running some commands, the other is used to test that commands.

If I use a real machine, I can ssh it to use multiple terminals, but in docker, how can I do this?

Maybe the solution is to `run` docker with CMD `/bin/bash`, and in that bash, using `screen`?

**EDIT**

`In my situation, one shell run a server program, the other run a client program to test the server program. Because the server program and client program are compiled together. So, the default link method in docker is not suitable.`

Comment: Not sure I understand. You need more then one shell? like one to run commands and the second to tail logs?

Comment: something like that, one shell run a server program, the other run a client program to test the server program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem, then you can use nsenter.
Assuming you have a running docker named **nginx** (with nginx started), run the following command from the host:

```
nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t `docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}}  nginx`
```

This will start a program in the given name space of the PID (default $SHELL).
You can run more then one shell by issuing it more then once (from the host). Then you can run any binary that exist in the given docker or tail, rm, etc files. For example, tail the log file of nginx.

Further information can be found in the [nsenter man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on your answer, I also find another tool which called `nsinit`. [It said](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/03/23/lxc-attach-nsinit-nsenter-docker-0-9/), "According to Michael Crosby, it is even better to use nsinit. And he's a core maintainer of Docker, and primary author of libcontainer; so you bet he knows what he's talking about"

Comment: Waiting for others advice. Thanks again!

Comment: This nsinit is an interesting solution. I still wonder why its better then nsenter. Will check that soon. thx

Answer (score 3):

The docker way would be to run the server in one container and the client in another. You can use links to make the server visible from the client and you can use volumes to make the files at the server available from the client. If you really want to have two terminals to the same container there is nothing stopping you from using ssh. I tested this docker server:

from: https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

```
# sshd
#
# VERSION               0.0.1

FROM     ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Thatcher R. Peskens "thatcher@dotcloud.com"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

You need to base this image on your image or the otherway around to get all the functionality together. After you have built and started your container you can get it's IP using

```
docker inspect <id or name of container>
```

from the docker host you can now ssh in with root and the password from the docker file. Now you can spawn as many ssh clients as you want. I tested with:

```
while true; do echo "test" >> tmpfile; sleep 1; done
```

from one client and

```
tail -f tmpfile
```

from another

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just play around, you can run `sshd` in your image and explore it the way you are used to:

```
 docker run -d -p 22 your_image /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

When you are done with your explorations, you can proceed to create Dockerfile as usual.

Comment: A reasonable solution to my situation. Though I must install sshd first. Thanks!

Comment: @HaveF So, you can run `/bin/bash` instead, quickly install `sshd` and run it in bash with `-D` and you are done! Also, you can `docker commit` your running sshd-installed container to new image for easier experimenting.